# Is polymer server push manifest at build time useful with Firebase or is firebase.json does the job?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting, polymer-2.x

I have notice that I can generate a push manifest in build process of my Polymer app but I am using Firebase as backend and I am trying to get h2 push to work.

Would I need to worry about this push-manifest.json or is it enough to fill in firebase.json like [here](https://github.com/Polymer/hn-polymer-2/blob/master/firebase.json)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting uses `firebase.json` as the only source for determining response headers. You don't need to worry about the Polymer push manifest if you've already added the information to `firebase.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Michael

Comment: @Michael Bleigh Based on the answer given, am I correct to say that firebase hosting does not natively support the `push-manifest.json` for h2 push, and definition of `push-manifest.json` must be defined in `firebase.json` as it is the only source to determine response headers? If so is there any helper script to generate `firebase.json` based on polymer generated `push-manifest.json`?

Comment: You are correct. I'm not aware of an existing helper script -- if you come across one, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: @MIchael Bleigh Thanks for the clarification. Here's a gist that I came across that inject `push-manifest.json` definition into `firebase.json`:- https://gist.github.com/jorgecasar/ef0e668d5c1f4faf7f1e50be89ea60d6 . Maybe`firebase-tools` could have something similar to support h2 push, just a suggestion.